# Periodically retrieve all rows to find the highest 100 counters

Tags: php, database, nosql, cassandra

I'm working on a cassandra database storing the amount of times a word occurred. I want to find out which 100 words occur the most times. In a relational database, it'd be something like this:

```
select * FROM wordcounter ORDER BY counts DESC LIMIT 100;
```

but ordering by a `counter-column` in cassandra is impossible.

So, instead I'll have to periodically (probably once per day) fetch **all** rows and write the 100 words with the highest counters to the db. The following is not an option;

```
select * FROM wordcounter
```

Because that would return way too much data. I'll have to do it in increments, but how (and how many rows per query is acceptable)?

**UPDATE**

It's supposedly possible to iterate over all cassandra rows, but I am using PHP `pdo` to communicate with cassandra & it certainly doesn't have an iterate feature as far as I've seen. But I found I can query by `token` so this is possible;

```
select * FROM wordcounter LIMIT 100;
```

And then keep looping this until 0 results are returned

```
select * FROM wordcounter WHERE token(word) > token('lastword') LIMIT 100;
```

So this basically is the equivelent of an `OFFSET` which will allow me to process parts of the dataset without having to query it all at once. But I guess this does mean I can't distribute the query over multiple systems. Does anyone know of any alternatives?

Comment: can you mention the field names of the `wordcounter` table?

Comment: @kumar_v It's just 'word' as the key, and 'counts' as the counter. Nothing else in there. Related data is in a seperate table.

Comment: I'm new to cassandra. why can't do order by counter-column in query? Is it restricted?

Comment: Indeed it is. You may only order by keys (partitioning or clustering) but counter columns can't be keys (of course.)

Comment: ok. `select word, sum(counts) as nocounter from wordcounter group by word having nocounter >=100`. this may help you. Please check it and let me know, i'll add it in answer

Comment: Cassandra CQL does not have sum. Also, I am not looking for rows with at least a counter of 100. I am looking for the 100 rows with the highest counter compared to the other rows' counters ;)